# Running tabulate area command on Esri tiled imagery layer

Tags: arcgis-pro, land-cover, tabulate

Esri recently released a tiled imagery layer of land cover at 10 meter resolution.  I'm interested in pulling stats from it based on county boundaries.  I tried using the Tabulate Area command and it works fine if I download a couple of image tiles (to cover a single state) mosaic them and then only pull stats for all the counties in the chosen state from the mosaic dataset.  What I'd like to do is use the tiled imagery layer (avoid download and mosaic step) as the raster data, loop through individual states, and calculate the county statistics I want.

This doesn't seem to work at all.  The tool hangs for a long time at 5% and eventually crashes with a useless error message. I also tried downloading the individual TIFF tiles they provide and creating a large mosaic but this fails as well (creates a huge file and fills up memory).  As long as the raster input is the entire imagery layer it fails.  My next try would be to download all the tiles for the US.  Look at each state and determine the minimum number of tiles to mosaic (programmatically), mosaic them and perform the tabulate on each state using the smaller raster dataset.  This would be very time consuming, fill up my hard drive and probably would end up failing as well if the mosaics were too big. (Hello Alaska)

Has anyone done something similar? Is it not feasible to use the entire tiled imagery layer as input into a geoprocessing tool in ArcGIS Pro?  Does memory enter into whether these operations will work to completion.  I can't imaging a single state's county boundaries are a problem but the extremely large raster dataset I am overlaying it on is.

Comment: ESRI people.   Can this format be used in geoprocessing tools like tabulate area?  It doesn't seem so.

Answer (score 0):

After consultation with ESRI technical support I found that to make this work it's important to not use a definition query on the vector layer.  Export the geography of interest into it's own feature class and then run this process.  It's not a quick process but it will run against the Tiled imagery layer.  I ran all the counties in Massachusetts (12 counties I believe) and it took around 30 minutes.